# When ojbect ref is updated should methods in new ref become accessible?

Tags: scala

In below code I'm updating the reference t from type T to type S. When I update the reference should I not be able to access methods on type S ? In below code `t.printS` does not compile .

```
   object liskov {

  //if S is a subtype of T, then objects
  //of type T may be replaced with objects of type S
  class T {

    def printT() {
      println("T")
    }

  }

  class S extends T {

    def printS() {
      println("S")
    }
  }

  var t: T = new T                                //> t  : liskov.T = liskov$T@1e152c5
  var s: S = new S                                //> s  : liskov.S = liskov$S@80d1ff

  println(t)                                      //> liskov$T@1e152c5
  t = s
  println(t)                                      //> liskov$S@80d1ff
  s.printS                                        //> S
  t.printS

}
```

Comment: Yes, when you update the reference now for all you see - it's a T and not an S (that's the whole point of the LSP, for T users, the fact your T is actually an S is irrelevant, they can behaviorally use it as a T).

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum so even though t is pointing to type S the methods on type S cannot be invoked from t ?

Comment: Imagine you have a method that accepts a T, now you pass it an S. If it could invoke S's methods, it could do so for any passed Ts since you don't know in advance they are really Ss, what happens when you pass it a T that is in fact _not_ an S? That'd call methods that don't exist on an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As those who commented had stated, only the static type of `var t: T` is available to enable access to the members of `t` *as such*. However, you can easily make a dynamic type query to distinguish instance of `T` from those of its subtypes:

```
t match {
  case s: S => /* here, s h as static type S and so printS is available */
  case _:   => /* here only the T's members are available (via t) */
}
```